# In the following pl sql program what is the error ? Is it a compilation error?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

```
Declare
 a VARCHAR2(10);
 b NUMBER;
BEGIN 
 a:=&empname;
 b:=&empno;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WELCOME'a||','||b||);
END;
```

When I am running it on oracle sql developer,  it is showing some some which I can not able to figure out.

Comment: how about post the error message?

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 32:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "A" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec as between from using || multiset member
   submultiset
The symbol "," was substituted for "A" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 7, column 43:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue

Comment: Why are you using substitution variables (e.g. `&empname`) instead of bind variables? That's a sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'`Welcome'a` is wrong. Try this:

```
    Declare 
         a VARCHAR2(10);
         b NUMBER; 
      BEGIN 
        a:=&empname; 
        b:=&empno;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WELCOME'||a||','||to_char(b) );
     END;
```

Comment: Here I gave the input 'raj'  and '10' Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RAJ' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @user3761068 there is something wrong about how you're passing the parameters. Are the between `'RAJ'`?

Comment: yes , I was giving input as RAJ  instead of 'RAJ'.Now it was executing successfully. Thank you.